# Distinct number of strings in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, count, distinct

**UPDATED WITH FIX**

I want to return only the number of unique entries in my array. The array contains a string variable that represents IP address. If there are 10 of them, but of 3 different kinds I just want to return 3. I have been at this all day and can't seem to figure out a solution that works. My code:

**Original code**

```
int getUnique(Visitors info[], string url, string startDate, string endDate){

int count = 0;

string temp;

for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++){

    if(url == info[i].URL && (dateChecker(startDate, endDate, info[i].dateAccessed))){



    }

}

return count;

}
```

**Updated code**

```
int getUnique(Visitors info[], string url, string startDate, string endDate){

set<string> ips;

for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++){

    if(url == info[i].URL && (dateChecker(startDate, endDate, info[i].dateAccessed))){

       ips.insert(info[i].IP);

    }

}

return ips.size();

}
```

The first if checks whether the matching URL does in fact match, and the `dateChecker` just makes sure that the date that the particular IP went to that URL is in between the 2 passed dates (`startDate` and `endDate`). How do I get the number of different IPs under these conditions?

Comment: You should not change the original question with the fix otherwise readers coming later on won't understand what happened. In general you want to append an edit section to the end of your question.

Comment: Edited the question to show both original and "fixed" code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), it stores items uniquely and it's efficient:

```
std::set<string> ips;

for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
  ips.insert(info[i].IP);

int unique_ips = ips.size();
```

Comment: sorry the IPs are a a variable of the Class Object (info[i].IP)

Comment: Wow I have never heard of this. So basically it is a data structure that will only store one occurence of each different string or data type you throw at it. So if I was using it for ints and I added like {1, 1, 6, 6, 4, 1, 15}. It would just store 1, 6, 4, and 15?

Comment: I'm getting an error stating that 'set' is not a member of std?

Comment: @Sherifftwinkie you need to include the header `#include <set>`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) to keep track of unique `string`s:

```
std::set<std::string> mySet ;
```

for each iteration just do:

```
mySet.insert( info[i].IP) ;
```

and at the end:

```
return mySet.size() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this lazily with set

```
std::set<string> uniq;
if(url == info[i].URL && (dateChecker(startDate, endDate, info[i].dateAccessed))){
        uniq.insert(info[i].URL);
}

return uniq.size();
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you need to use std::set however there is no need to manually iterate array, since std::map accepts iterators to range it should be constructed from. Thus

```
std::map<std::string> unique(strinvec.begin(), stringvec.end());
```

Should do the trick.
And if you need to know only count of unique elements, you may use even shorter notation.

```
size_t unique_count = std::map<std::string>(strinvec.begin(), stringvec.end()).size();
```